# Создание окошка, всегда висящего поверх всего

Tags: .net, winforms

Создаю менеджер для буфера обмена. Для этого хочу создать черную полоску с кнопочками, которая всегда будет поверх всего висеть в правой части экрана, наподобие нижней полосы в Windows. Соответственно без рамок и.т.д. На этой панельки буду помещать функциональные кнопочки. С помощью какой формы и каких свойств можно было-бы реализовать такую интерактивную панель без рамочек, висящую поверх всех приложений?

Comment: А если два таких окошка запустить, то как они могут было одно поверх другого?

Comment: Попробовал. Поверх висит последнее активное из них. То есть между собой они взаимодействуют так же, как между собой взаимодействуют обычные окна без приоритета.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно установить [свойство Form.TopMost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx) формы в `true`. Оно позволит форме перекрывать другие.
Для отрисовки формы без границ [свойство Form.FormBorderStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) установить в `None`